# In R, how do I detect file access?

Tags: r, logging, callback, file-access

I would like to write a [callback function](https://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf) that detects and logs any file-access during an R session.

There are tons of different built-in ways to open a connection in R so it's unreliable to search 'open','file','url','read','save', etc. in the `expression` argument of my callback function. There must be some generic event that all these different connection-manipulating functions converge on, right?

So, how do I detect such an event programatically in a platform-agnostic way?  Thanks.

The following does not work. I guess the connections are already closed by the time the callback is triggered...

```
cb <- taskCallbackManager();
cb$add(function(xpr,val,ok,visible){
  if(length( cons<-showConnections())>0) print( cons) 
  else print('0');
  TRUE;
},'mycb');

# [1] "mycb"
# [1] "0"

sample <- read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/ara/angell.txt")

# [1] "0"
```

Comment: Functions registered with `taskCallbackManager` will always only run after the top-level function has completed. If any function opens and closes a connection within the body you'll never be able to detect it that way. R isn't set up to run async code. Seems like you'd have to alter the R internal source code to make a change like this.

Comment: I was hoping that file opens/closes are an obvious sort of thing to be some kind of even that R can respond to, and I just don't have the right words to Google it (for example, before I found callbacks, I wasted some time reading about hooks). It seems like there would *have* to be one or a limited number of events, in order for R to be embeddable...

Comment: R interacts with files via connections. Those functions are [defined here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/44bbfcd2e64750c8510e91883f5d8d5608a012bf/src/main/connections.c). I don't see any obvious hooks in there. Not use I understand the argument about embeddablility.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not found an answer but I have found a workaround. Most file access functions follow a similar syntax, with the location of the file as the first argument so I wrote a wrapper that works with most of them following this pattern:

```
tread <- function(file,...,readfun){
  filename <- deparse(match.call()$file);
  loaded <- readfun(file,...);
  # put your logging/MD5-check/whatever here
  return(loaded);
}
```

It can even be used transparently in a multi-author setting by locally reassigning for example `read_csv` to the wrapper at the beginning of the script or some global config file such that readfun is a fully qualified name of, in this case, `readr::read_csv`